# "App crashed" no log do Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, servidor, heroku

Estou tendo um problema na minha aplicação Node que está no servidor do Heroku. Quando faço muitos requests para a mesma rota `/oapi/login` a aplicação para de rodar, o error que o log me retorna é esse:

```
2020-01-18T14:41:27.184911+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=OPTIONS path="/oapi/login" host=expenses-server-api.herokuapp.com request_id=171e102c-befe-45d2-9415-6899a84adf54 fwd="201.182.211.10" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

E então não consigo mais acessar outras rotas da aplicação.

**Observações:**

- Estou usando o Mongoose para a conexão com o banco
- O arquivo **package.json** está configurado corretamente
- O arquivo **Procfile** está correto também
- Todas as variáveis de ambiente estão setadas

Comment: Posta o código da rota, acredito que esteja sobrecarregando o servidor, por isso ele crasha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No código eu apenas estava enviando resposta sem fazer nenhuma tratativa de Exceção, então quando qualquer conexão com o banco fosse feita, eu coloquei o bloco `try / catch`.

Código Antigo:

```
await Model.find((err, resp) => {
   if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json(err);
   } else {
      return res.status(200).json(resp);
   }
});
```

Código Atual:

```
try {
   await Model.find((err, resp) => {
      if (err) {
         return res.status(400).json(err);
      } else {
         return res.status(200).json(resp);
      }
   });
} catch (err) {
   return res.status(400).json(err);
}
```

É claro que esse foi o meu caso, o seu pode ser diferente, porém agora posso fazer quantas requisições erradas que o servidor não vai para (App Crashed).